# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Md-Azharuddin02/one.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2088 after 2366 ms: Couldn't connect to

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Md-Azharuddin02/one.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2088 after 2366 ms: Couldn't connect to server

The following error i am getting while publishing project fro vs code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hEx6.png)

if you guys have any idea about this error then please help me out

Comment: seems like you are trying to use a proxy service that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the exact reason of this error but I have solved anyhow.

git config --global --unset http.proxy

just paste the above line in the command prompt and your problem will be solved.